Android Bottom NavigationView taking too much height
I am not using any style/theme or any complex customization on it yet Bottom Navigation view is taking unexpected height,
I am using wrap_content for height so got following output:

 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    **android:layout_height="wrap_content"**
    app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

and when using fixed height i.e ?attr/actionbarsize I am getting following output(all icons/labels collapsed):

code:
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

Full code of Layout:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AppInstalledCheckActivity"
    android:background="#FFEB3B">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittextPackageName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:hint="Enter Package Name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCheckInstalled"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Enter Package Name" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navgraph" />

     <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


</LinearLayout>

I want it to have equal or similar height as tool/actionbar.

Two changes needs to be made:
Change root LinearLayout to RelativeLayout:
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AppInstalledCheckActivity">

Comment/remove windowInsetsListener from activity's oncreate method
/*        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }*/

Final XML:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AppInstalledCheckActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittextPackageName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:hint="Enter Package Name" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCheckInstalled"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:text="Enter Package Name" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navgraph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


</RelativeLayout>

Output:

you need to change systemBars.bottom to 0
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
    val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    //v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
    v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, 0)
    insets
}


You need to change
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        **android:layout_height="400dp"**
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navgraph" />

to
**android:layout_height="match_parent"**


i did this and bottom nav went below the screen as fragmentcontainer took whole height.
this cant be the solution as height of the bottom nav has nothing to do with the height of other child views under it's parent layour.
@jamal

i have fixed and have written correct answer, kindly check.
